# Searching for a word in sentence

Tags: python, regex

I want a Python function that can get a keyword from an input of a sentence and a list of keywords. The function will iterate over the keywords list and search in the sentence the given keywords. If there is a keyword in the sentence, the function will return the keyword. Else it will return None.

For example, I have a list ["ai", "Machine Learning", "Computer Science"] and a sentence **"My major is Computer Science, and I am currently working as a retailer for a store"**. If the function is implemented correctly, it will output the keyword *Computer Science*. However, at the moment, my function is outputting both *Computer Science* and *ai* (*retailer* also has *ai* in it) since I am using Python *IN*. Is there any way that I can improve my function to get the more proper result?

Here is my attempted code:

```
sentence = "My major is Computer Science, and I am currently working as a retailer for a store"

keywords_list = ["ai", "Machine Learning", "Computer Science"]

output_list = list()

for keyword in keywords_list:
    if keyword in sentence:
        output_list.append(keyword)
```

Comment: Please share your attempted code.

Comment: Maybe try a regex that ensures there's a word boundary on either end of your term? e.g. `re.search(f'\\b{your_term}\\b', your_phrase)`

Comment: hint: split your sentence by its blank spaces, e.g. your_sentence.split(' ')

Comment: I have updated my code in the post. @GreenCloakGuy I will try your code and let you know if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best path for this is using a regex because if you just use `in`, it will match since `ai` is in the word `retailer`. You can use word boundaries in regex (`\b`).

```
>>> import re
>>> keywords = "|".join(keywords_list)
>>> re.findall(f"\\b({keywords})\\b", sentence)
['Computer Science']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do:

```
sentence = "My major is Computer Science, and I am currently working as a retailer for a store"

keywords_list = ["ai", "Machine Learning", "Computer Science"]

alph = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

output_list = list()

for keyword in keywords_list:
    
    k = [''.join([w for w in key if w.lower() in alph]) for key in keyword.split()] # List of all the words in keyword, with all punctuations removed
    s = [''.join([w for w in wor if w.lower() in alph]) for wor in sentence.split()] # List of all the words in sentence, with all punctuations removed
    
    if any([k == s[i:len(k)+i] for i in range(len(s)-len(k))]): # If any of the lists in keyword equals to any slice of the sentence list
        output_list.append(keyword) # That means that the keyword is in
        
print(output_list)
```

Output:

```
['Computer Science']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = input("sentence here: ").casefold()
keywords = ["ai", "Machine Learning", "Computer Science"]
# making all keywords lower case
for keyword in keywords:
    keywords[keywords.index(keyword)] = keyword.casefold()

result= ""
#searching
for keyword in keywords:
    if keyword in sentence:
        result += "{} ".format(keyword)
if result == "":
    result = None
print(result)
```

Comment: How is that? if you're copying the code you should reformat the code from your IDE

Comment: You cannot split by spaces because the keywords may contain spaces

Comment: I didn't notice that

Comment: @Mathew the code above still outputs the wrong result. As I said in the post, *ai* is also in *retailer*. Anyway, I found the solution. Thank you so much!!!